# Generation of list of values for small gap among values

Tags: numerics, list-manipulation, warning-messages, precision-and-accuracy

I need to run a loop as

```
Table[expr,{i,imin,imax,di}]
```

where I want `di` to be as small as order of `2^(-100)`.
However *Mathematica* 8.0 seems not to support me for such small `di` and generates a message
"Iterator does not have appropriate bounds".
What can be the solution?

Comment: `s = 2^(-100); Table[i, {i, s, 5 s, s}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With integers and rational numbers for `imin`, `imax`, and `di` it should work.

```
di = 2^(-100)
imin = 1
imax = imin + 10 di

Table[Numerator[i] - Denominator[i], {i, imin, imax, di}]
```

> ```
> {0, 1, 1, 3, 1, 5, 3, 7, 1, 9, 5}
> ```

Comment: may be i am making some logical error, while selecting imax for my particular problem. I try to resolve it in light of your suggestion and will update about details. Thank you

Comment: @zenith If `(imax-imin)/di` is unreasonably large, you'll get the "Iterator does not have appropriate bounds" error message.